# WP - AutoCompleteBox get list of items with bigger font size

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, autocompletebox

This is my code fo ACB:

```
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acbAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource autoCompleteWordList}, Path=ListOfAddresses}" 
                         TextChanged="acbAddress_TextChanged" KeyUp="acbAddress_KeyUp" 
                             Style="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxStyle1}"
                         SelectionChanged="AcbAddress_OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

And I found this to get Text_OnSelectionChanged working for my cursor to set right position. But now I have popup with very little font size. How can I now set font size for items in popup?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CommonValidationToolTipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="Translation" X="-25"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <BackEase Amplitude=".3" EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualTransition>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Root"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Border Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5" Margin="4,4,-4,-4"/>
                <Border Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3,3,-3,-3"/>
                <Border Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2,2,-2,-2"/>
                <Border Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2" Margin="1,1,-1,-1"/>
                <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" MaxWidth="250" Margin="8,4,8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" UseLayoutRounding="false"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxStyle1" TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
                    <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Text" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" IsTabStop="True" Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" SelectionChanged="Text_OnSelectionChanged"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="#11000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <ListBox x:Name="Selector" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just give a custom `Item` style via `ItemContainerStyle` by targeting the `ListBoxItem` like;

```
<Style  x:Key="myItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Khaki" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" /><!-- Your Property -->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
</Style>


<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myItemStyle}" />
```

You could also use `BasedOn` to inherit the rest of the existing style stuff from the default template into your `Style` so you would only be changing the `FontSize`

More detailed info found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.